# The "correct" way to handle remote iOS push notifications in react-native?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, react-native, apple-push-notifications

I'm having problems getting push notifications to work adequately in react-native 0.38 iOS.  Specifically there seems to be an issue around handling push notifications after the OS has terminated the app.

It seems that when your app is in a background state, iOS will kill it at some point (presumably in order to free up memory for other processes).  And from my experiments it appears that iOS will terminate an app from the background state quite liberally - it's a very common thing.  However, if the OS does terminate your app from the background state, it will also revive it should a push notification arrive so long as that notification contains the important `content-available=1` flag, AND you've allowed *Remote Notifications* in background modes for your app.

As of RN0.38, if you receive a push notification that has the `content-available=1` flag, you MUST call the `finish` method which in turn invoke the *fetchCompletionHandler*.  If you don't invoke the *completionHandler*, the OS will penalise your app for taking up resources and will slow down (or stop) notification delivery - which it does (again quite liberally).  I believe you have around 30 seconds of wall clock time to call the *fetchCompletionHandler*, after which the OS will put you on its naughty list and your app will stop working properly.

So, from the **terminated state** I can see a push notification arriving, and I can see the OS starting my app. In my `AppDelegate` I have this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  UILocalNotification *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

  if (remoteNotif) {
    NSLog(@"push notification when app is not open");
  }
  ...
```

And I see the message "push notification when app is not open" in the logs. All Good.  It works fine when the app is in the foreground and when it's in the background, but not so when terminated.

The next thing to happen is that `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` get's called:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  NSLog(@"push-notification with content body => %@", notification);

  if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    NSLog(@"push-notification app:Inactive");
  } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    NSLog(@"push-notification app:Background");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"push-notification app:Active");
  }

  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

And in the logs, as expected I see *"push-notification app:Background"*.  But, **immediately** after this line in the logs I see the following warning:

```
Nov 28 10:53:17 Tests-iPhone myapp[1139] <Notice>: push-notification app:Background
Nov 28 10:53:17 Tests-iPhone myapp(UIKit)[1139] <Notice>: Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.
```

From this it looks to me as if the app is not given any time at all to process the incoming push notification.  The warning that the *completionHandler* was not called happens immediately and my JS code doesn't get a chance to run.  I do not see this message when the app is running in the foreground or background.

I suppose my question is - *how do you get a react-native app to gracefully handle an iOS push notification that arrives after the OS has terminated the app*?

From the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4) I gather that an approach to this is to start a background task as soon as a notification arrives.  I don't see anywhere in the RN code base where a background task is started, and I'm now actually wondering how push notifications work when the app is in the background **without** starting a background task.

As an experiment I tried the following, it's a dirty hack, but my app started behaving better in this situation:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  NSLog(@"push-notification with content body => %@", notification);

  if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    NSLog(@"push-notification app:Inactive");
  } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    NSLog(@"push-notification app:Background");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"push-notification app:Active");
  }

  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];

//start hack
  self.pnBgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyPNTask" expirationHandler:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask:self.pnBgTask];
    self.pnBgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
  }];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:25.0f];//dodgy hack to give it a chance to complete the 'real' bg-task

    [application endBackgroundTask:self.pnBgTask];
    self.pnBgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
  });
//end hack
}
```

With this change my app appears to work much better when running from xCode, but I haven't tried it out in *real deployed* app yet.

Thanks for any ideas.

By the way, in order to test this you either need to get iOS to terminate you app (which as far as I can see is close to impossible to do), or - either simply stop it form inside Xcode or [change the launch settings](https://medium.com/@milkservice/there-is-an-easier-way-in-scheme-settings-there-is-an-option-wait-for-executable-to-be-launched-b145d85d17e0#.hz4oaqage)  to use "Wait for executable to be launched", then send your push notification and the app will start from a terminated state.

Comment: Did you figure out a good way to solve this? I'm using RN 0.40 and have been struggling for days to trigger my javascript code when the app has gone to background mode.